# Classic ASP - Check how many numbers are in a variable

Tags: asp-classic

Im wondering if someone could help me.

I need to get the amount of numbers in a variable.

So for instance:

```
number = Int(34324)
```

Would contain 5 and so on.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Len()` function:

```
digitCount = Len(CStr(number))
```